# LTspice - analyze current with varying resistance

Tags: current-measurement, ltspice

I would like to graph current from V1 over varying resistance instead of voltage.  Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Try to use .op analysis instead of transient.

Comment: OK kinda worked.  If I use -V(n002) to plot I get the graph I want, but not the units.

Answer (score 3):

The are (at least) four fundamental methods for varying a load in LTSpice. For your application I think method 3 is going to be the winner, but let me outline them so you can evaluate:

**Method 1: .step**

As in your question, simple but no time domain control.

**Method 2: Switch Model**

Good for time-domain control of step-wise resistor changes. The presence of the switch model in the current path can complicate things, and gets cumbersome if there are lots of step-wise changes.

[image: Switch Model]

**Method 3: Variable Parameters**

Set your resistor's resistance to an expression involving `V(netname)`, and then drive that net with a variable voltage of your choice.

[image]

Very simple to include in circuit and very powerful to control because you can use any voltage source circuit.

**Method 4: Behavioural Sources**

Similar to Method 3, but use a behavioural source (bi or bv) instead of a passive component.

[image]

Adds the extra feature of controlling a source rather than a sink.

Comment: Thanks!  Let me work on this and see.  Back later with update.

Comment: BTW what is the link to that reference material?

Comment: I'm not sure what reference material you're referring, but I draw most of my inspiration from the surprisingly excellent built-in manual.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to vary resistance in a transient simulation the best way to do this is with a node that has a source with the values for resistance and change that node.

Resistors can be set to the same value as a voltage node (so you could have resistors that vary with a sine/square or anything a voltage source can produce). Below is shown how to do this with a PWL source. The amplitude of the voltage source will be the same resistor values. The resistor must be set to the same node name with a V() function to only get the voltage of that net/node.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems the default Save Device Current was turned off in Control Panel.  After correcting that issue and using DC Operating Point (.op) I got what I was trying to plot.

[image: I/{X} Plot]

Answer (score 0):

This is just an addendum to @HeathRaftery's answer, the part with the switch. By using a negative threshold voltage, both the `level 1` and `level 2` switches have a smooth, nonlinear transition from ON to OFF resistances, so by solving for the conductance/resistance and applying that voltage to the switch, it is possible to precisely control the variation of the resistance.

For the `level 2`, the formula is given in the manual:

\$g(V_c)=\exp(A\arctan(\frac{V_c-V_t}{|V_h|})+B)\$
\$A=\frac{1}{\pi}\log(\frac{R_{off}}{R_{on}}), B=\frac12\log(\frac{1}{R_{on}R_{off}})\$

Solving for the resistance, you get:

\$V_c=V_t-\tan(\frac{R+B}{A})|V_h|\$

where \$R\$ is the varying resistance. This formula can be used with a behavioural source. If the variation needs to be linear, it could look like this:

```
V=Vt-tan( (log( R(time) ) + B)/A )*abs(Vh)
```

with

```
.func R(x) {x/simulation*(Roff-Ron)+Ron}
.param simulation=3 Roff=1k Ron=1 A=log(Roff/Ron)/pi B=log(1/Roff/Ron)/2
```

where `simulation` represents the total simulation time (e.g. `tran {simulation}`; optional, for better control). Here's a quick example:

[image: test]

where the parameters for the `PWL` source have been defined as `Vmin=Vt-abs(Vh) Vmax=Vt+abs(Vh)`. You can see plotted `V(l2)` vs `V(test)`, which are the normal variation of the resistance for the `level 2` switch when a linear ramp between `Vmin` and `Vmax` is applied, compared to its direct, behavioural expression, and `V(ctl)`, where it's desired that the resistance varies linearly, defined as in the example above.

For the `level 1` switch, there is no formula in the LTspice manual, but there is in the PSpice manual. Search for `PSPCREF.PDF` on the Internet and at page `222` you'll find what you're looking for, but you'll see that it's actually a 3<sup>rd</sup> order polynomial, which means solving for the controlling voltage will result in a fairly involved formula. Despite the \$\tan()\$ in the `level 2` switch, it's more readable. The choice belongs to you.